# Batch create Leaflet webmaps in QGIS

Tags: qgis, leaflet, web-mapping, batch

During a project on the spider fauna of Greece, we have to face the design of distribution maps of the species.

A good tool to work with is the design of Leaflet webmaps to be used on the website instead of static maps.

As the number of species is not small (1120 species = 1120 maps) am looking to find a way to create under a batch mode, webmaps with the Leaflet plugin.

All data are stored in a csv or shapefile with one column contain species name and rest the source (literature code) and coordinates in WGS84

Any idea on how can this work?

Comment: what's the data look like?  points/line/spolygons/raster? total feature count?  estimate feature count per species?  and what are your website capabilities?  1120 different tilelayers is a lot (obviously).

Comment: are you wanting to do this with QGIS server?

Comment: Point Data, ~ 13000 records = 2500 locations. QGIS Server could be an option indeed

Comment: Instead of generating 1120 different maps, I think it worth considering setting up an application that pulls the points data from a database after the user selects species. While this would take more effort to develop the back end, its probably worth it.  You might consider something like GeoServer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that with 13,000 records you might still get away with a single app loading a GeoJSON or TopoJSON file.

Are you interested in sharing the data?

I've got a single page web-app that allows you to explore a [bunch of data about crashes here](http://agl.pw/examples/crash2/). If you use the clustering plugin, you get better performance. And then you can turn the clusters off when you zoom in.

Building a single-page app also lets you build some selectors for the data, such as dropdowns. These can be populated dynamically from the data.

Answer (score 0):

While qgis2web does not explicitly expose an API, it would be possible to write a python script to load each dataset sequentially, and export it to Leaflet. You would need reasonable knowledge of Python and the QGIS API to achieve this.

Update

qgis2web can now be called as a QGIS Processing algorithm. While this is still under development, it allows batch processing to produce multiple web maps.